# Decimal separator setting for the Spotlight calculator

Tags: macos, spotlight

I use the Spotlight calculator a lot but since the upgrade to OS X Mavericks the decimal pointer has changed to a `,` instead of the `.` as in a previous release. Probably it now respects some locale setting but I cannot find which.

I reside in a German speaking country but use a US keyboard, the interface is set to English, the region formats are set to United States (with the exception of the currency being set to Euro), see this screenshot.

[image: Language & Region settings]

Still, the calculator expects a `,` as a decimal separator:

```
1+.5
```

gives no result, while

```
1+,5
```

prints `1+,5 = 1,5`

How can I change the decimal separator back to a `.`?

**Edit:** As you can see in the screenshot the decimal point is set to `.` through these settings. Spotlight ignores that setting until you reboot (which I hadn't done at the time).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can change the settings from the `Advanced...`button in the Language & Region preference pane.

Remember that you have to either reboot or log out for the changes to be applied to Spotlight!

[image]

Comment: In addition, the free utility Alfred gives you the option of treating both the comma and the period as decimal separators simultaneously. This has come in handy on occasion when I am pasting in numbers formatted both ways. The above is better as a canonical solution.

Comment: Well, as you can see in my screenshot (on the right bottom you can see sample values), I have the settings exactly as I want them (grouping `,`, decimal `.`). Still Spotlight only accepts a `,` as a decimal point.

Comment: That's strange, I managed to change the decimal separator from here and it got applied when I logged in again or rebooted.

Comment: If you don't like rebooting, kill the SystemUIServer process. Type `sudo killall SystemUIServer` in the terminal. This will reload the spotlight configuration.